# Does there exist a derivative of the Golden Ratio (equation)?

Tags: derivatives, definition, golden-ratio

On my calculus exam, there was a question asking "Is the Golden Ratio differentiable? If so, use the definition of a derivative to show it."

The "definition of a derivative" is $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h$

Is this possible? I've already taken the exam, so now I'm just curious as to what the real answer is.

---

Edit: That was all the question asked. I'm assuming it is referring to the definition of the golden ratio, $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}2.$

Edit 2: Sorry about my formatting. It's atrocious, I know. Gotta love mobile.

Comment: The usual "definition" of the golden ratio is $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt5}{2}$, whatever that's worth.

Comment: If by Golden Ratio the constant function $f(x) =\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ is meant, then by all means the answer is yes, just as any constant function. Also, the definition of the derivative should probably be $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: @Ennar Would that make the derivative 0 then? And yes, that is what the definition is; my formatting is horrible because of the mobile application.

Comment: That's a strange question in a calculus exam but yes, the derivative is $0$ since it's a constant.

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to show it for any constant?

Comment: @Ennar No, I don't think that I do. We haven't discussed the derivative of a constant function yet, which is why this question threw me off.

Comment: That's easy. If $f$ is a constant function, then $\forall x,h,\, f(x+h)=f(x)$, so...

Comment: @Augustin It was a very odd Calculus exam, especially for the first of 3 Calculus classes.